# How to pass method name to custom server control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, custom-server-controls, web-controls

I am working on a Customer Server Control that extends another control.  There is no problem with attaching to other controls on the form.

in vb.net:  `Parent.FindControl(TargetControlName)`

I would like to pass a method to the control in the ASPX markup.

for example: `<c:MyCustomerControl runat=server InitializeStuffCallback="InitializeStuff">`

So, I tried using reflection to access the given method name from the Parent.

Something like (in VB)

```vb
Dim pageType As Type = Page.GetType
Dim CallbackMethodInfo As MethodInfo = pageType.GetMethod( "MethodName" )

'Also tried 
sender.Parent.GetType.GetMethod("MethodName")
sender.Parent.Parent.GetType.GetMethod("MethodName")
```

The method isn't found, because it just isn't apart of the Page.  Where should I be looking?  I'm fairly sure this is possible because I've seen other controls do similar.

---

I forgot to mention, my work-around is to give the control events and attaching to them in the Code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass a method in the ASPX markup, you need to use the `Browsable` attribute in your code on the event.

VB.NET

```vb
<Browsable(True)> Public Event InitializeStuffCallback
```

C#

```
[Browsable(true)]
public event EventHandler InitializeStuffCallback;
```

Reference:
[Design-Time Attributes for Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx) and [BrowsableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

All the events, properties, or whatever need to be in the code-behind of the control with the browsable attribute to make it so you can change it in the tag code.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you wouldn't need to get the method via reflection. Inside your user control, define a public event (sorry I do not know the vb syntax so this will be in c#)

```
public event EventHandler EventName;
```

Now, inside your aspx page, or whatever container of the user control, define a protected method that matches the EventHandler:

```
protected void MyCustomerControl_MethodName(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Now, inside your markup, you can use

```
<c:MyCustomerControl id="MyCustomerControl" runat=server OnEventName="MyCustomerControl_MethodName">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround is actually the better answer.  If you have code that you must run at a certain part of your control's lifecycle, you **should** expose events to let the container extend the lifecycle with custom functionality.

Comment: This is still possible.  It just allows it to be configured from the control tag instead of doing it from the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Every ASP.NET page is **class of its own** inherited from `Page` as in:

```
class MyPage : Page
```

Therefore, to find that method via Reflection, you must get the correct type, which is the type of the page class that stores the page code.

I suppose you need to support multiple pages for this control to be instantiated in I believe you can find the child type of any instance of Page via Reflection, but I do not remember how, but you should be able to do it.

but... like everyone else has said, such case is what *events* are for.

Answer (score 0):

buyutec and Jesse Dearing both have an acceptable answer.

```
[Browsable(true)]
```

lets you see the property in the Properties window.  However, the event doesn't show up, which makes no difference to me.

The thing I overlooked earlier was the fact that when you reference a control's even from the tag, it prep-ends On.